Translating "east–west" and "north–south"
In many railway transit systems, the lines connecting the north/east part and the south/west part of a city are called "North–South Line" and "East–West Line". In many languages like English, two direction names standing in juxtaposition are grammatically legal, but it seems of bad Latinity to do the same in Latin.
However, using a compound adjective is common in later Latin, especially in scientific nomenclature. So I want to make two adjectives for "east–west" and "north–south" for translation. I would like the name as short as possible, so the lengthy septentrionalis and meridianus are ruled out. Now I have several options:

for North–South:

based on boreas/-alis and auster/-tralis:

linking two adjectives: Linea Boreal-Autralis / Boreali-Australis.

australoccidentalis (without references) appears in Vicipaedia for a few times.


noun-adjective: Linea Borea(/Boreo)-Australis / Boreaustralis.

austro-orientalis appears in Norstedts svensk-latinska ordbok; austrorientalis appears in the species name Lupinus austrorientalis.
Boreas is a Hellenic α-stem noun; I wonder if using linking -a- is better than -o-.


noun-noun genitive: Linea Borea(/Boreo)-Austri / Boreaustri.


based on βορέας and νότος:

making a Hellenic adjective: Linea Boreanotia/Boreonotia (< νότιος).




for East–West:

based on oriens/-talis and occidens/-talis:

linking two adjectives: Linea Oriental(i)-Occidentalis
noun-adjective: Linea Orienti-Occidentalis / Orientoccidentalis


based on ortus and occasus:

noun-noun genitive: Linea Ortu-Occasi / Ortuoccasi

ortu- for ortus as manu- for manus in manutergium.


noun-adjective: Linea Ortu-Occasualis

occasualis is unattested.




based on ortus and occiduus:

noun-adjective: Linea Ortu-Occidua


based on ἑῷος and ἕσπερος:

making a Hellenic adjective: Linea (H)ĕōĕspera.





Which are the best to choose?

A rule of thumb I've heard is: Never use hyphens in Latin. I look forward to seeing an unhyphenated idea that someone comes up with.

Perhaps longitudinalis and latitudinalis, or something like linea borealis australisque, or more cumbersomely linea qua a borea ad austrum vehitur.
